# Hover срабатывает но остается на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Допустим на элементе применил hover, хорошо. На пк работает так как и должен работать. Но на тачскринах, hover срабатывает но не возвращает свойства когда касания нету...

Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим, есть ли решение?

Answer (score 0):

На тачскринах так и должно быть. Свойства возвратятся после нажатия вне блока.